# Why the warning is showing?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am doing work on application but this warning is showing when we use api of change password.

> This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background
>   thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes. This
>   will cause an exception in a future release.

[image]

api is running successfully that password is changed but i am not getting why this warning is coming.

i am using this code for using api:-

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
            NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];


     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:
xxx.com.api/changepassword"];
                NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];

            [request addValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];


            [request addValue:@"*/*" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];

            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

            NSString *mapData = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"regOldPassword=%@&memberId=5&newPassword=%@",string1, string2];

            NSData *postData = [mapData dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

            [request setHTTPBody:postData];

            NSLog(@" Edited data %@", mapData);

            //NSLog(@"email passed id%@",emailstr);


            NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

                if(error == nil)
                {

                    NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                    NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);


                    NSError *error = nil;
                    NSDictionary *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

                    UIAlertView * alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Password Changes Successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alert1 show];

                    if(error!=nil)
                    {

                        NSLog(@"error = %@",error);

                    }

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self checkUserSuccessfullySaved:json];
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    UIAlertView * alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Unsuccessful" message:@"Failed to change password please try again" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
                    [alert1 show];

                    NSLog(@"Error : %@",error.description);
                }
            }];
            [postDataTask resume];
        }




}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't show alerts from the background thread:

```
UIAlertView * alert1 = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Success" message:@"Password Changes Successfully" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert1 show];
```

must be dispatched to the main (UI) queue.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
   UIAlertView *alert1 = ...
   [alert1 show]; 
});
```

Note the stack indices 29 & 28:

```
[ChangePassword submit:]
```

method is the original cause of your problem because it shows an alert while being called on a background thread.

Comment: so what is the solution of this problem

Comment: i used this but again the same warning is showing

Comment: The solution is to read up on GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) and use what you learn.